# How to map form elements to two pojo object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have 2 pojo.

- user.java
- userrole.java

i have 1 jsp page called enrolluser.jsp, here i have information about user and userrole pojo.
Usually in spring mvc form binding, we can bind form object to only one pojo, how can i map user related fields from jsp to user pojo and user role related fields in jsp to userrole pojo uisng form binding functionality.

I have searched the net but could not find a suitable answer.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242394/spring-mvc-multiple-modelattribute-on-the-same-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a form class let say `UserInfo` and have `user` and `userrole` objects in it.

```
Class UserInfo
{
  private User user;
  private Userrole userrole;

  // create getter and setter for above fields.
}
```

Now if `userInfo` is an instance of class `UserInfo` in jsp, so use below code to access `User` and `UserRole` in jsp

```
${userInfo.user.name} // to access name from user

${userInfo.userrole.role} // to access role from userrole
```

Comment: how can i display a model data in page. suppose userInfo.user.name