# send two object from jsp to controller spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hello every one I have a register jsp and I need to send two object(Compte,Personne) please there is any way to send the two to the controller

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242394/spring-mvc-multiple-modelattribute-on-the-same-form

Comment: You take the different attributes from your request and dispatch them to the correct objects. To send them via the request, you use a form for the post method or the url for the get method...

Comment: please can you make an example with jsp and post mehod thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can put your objects: `Compte` and `Personne` into: `Map<String, Object> objectsMap = new HashMap();`. Then in your controller get them by key: `objectsMap.get("personne");`

Also, try to use Spring Forms and receive object via `@ModelAttribute`.