# Can we use BindingResult for each object in same controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am passing data to two objects from a single html form and in controller I have to use two objects. So, I want to know if I can use the BindingResult for each object in same controller in order to show the errors if it occurred.

Comment: It would be much helpful if you share some code snippets.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you receive two objects from one form in the controller, you must have two `BindingResult`s beacause one `BindingResult` contains the result of the validation of the object **right before it** in the signature of the controller's method.

So your controller should look like that :

```java
@PostMapping("...")
public String handlePost(@Valid Object1 object1, BindingResult result1, @Valid Object2 object2, BindingResult result2) {
```

Maybe you should have look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242394/spring-mvc-multiple-modelattribute-on-the-same-form)